# How do I determine whether a graph is singly connected or not?

Tags: algorithm, graph, connectivity, edges

If a graph has back edges, is it singly connected or not? By back edges I mean connections from child node to one of its ancestors, under the same root. If a node is connected to a node higher than it, but not its ancestor, then it's a cross node.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree

This link clarifies the concept of singly connected graph.

Comment: Please clarify what "singly connected" means. Did you want to check whether there are any cycles in the graph?

Comment: So, you meant 'Singly connected network' or Polytree?

Comment: one and the same. Its in the article.

Comment: Is that a directed graph? 
If so, a directed graph G = (V, E) is singly connected if u ->v implies that G contains **at most** one simple path from u to v for all vertices u, v ∊ V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a graph has back edges, that doesn't prevent it from being singly-connected. But it might not be singly-connected for other reasons. For example, if the graph is undirected.

Comment: I know that if a graph has forward or same-component cross edges then we can conclusively say that the graph is not singly connected. But is it so for back edges?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to know whether a Polytree can contain back edges (edges from a node to one of its ancestors).

From the wikipedia article you linked to, a Polytree is a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) that remains a tree even if the edges are made undirected. If a directed graph contained back edges, it would mean there would be a cycle in the graph (you can reach the node from its ancestor and then go back to the ancestor using the back edge). Thus it would no longer be a DAG, let alone a tree. If it isn;t a DAG, it cannot be a Polytree. So, no a Polytree cannot have a back edge.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are trying to make an analogy with linked lists (where singly-connected and doubly-connected are common terms with an usual meaning).

However, this isn't a big deal for graphs, and the term connectivity is more usually associated with *reachability* (ie.: is there a path from a node to another?)

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear. I was not referring to singly connected linked lists. Please refer to my update.